# Can I construct a Turing machine that accepts only its own encoding?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Is the set $S$ = $\lbrace M \mid M \text{ is a Turing machine and }L(M)=\lbrace \langle M\rangle\rbrace\rbrace$ empty?

In other words is there a Turing machine $M$ that only accepts its own encoding? What about a Turing machine that rejects only its own encoding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.

See [Kleene's second recursion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Kleene.27s_second_recursion_theorem): for any  partial recursive function $Q(x,y)$ there is an index $p$ such that $\varphi_p \simeq \lambda y.Q(p,y)$.

Suppose that $M$ is a Turing machine that on input $\langle x,y \rangle$ accepts if and only if $x=y$; then, by the above theorem, exists $M'$ such that $M'(\langle y \rangle) = M(\langle M' , y \rangle)$ and we have $L(M') = \{ \langle M' \rangle \}$.

P.S. you can find a very clear proof of the recursion theorem in Chapter 6 of the M. Sipser's book "Introduction to the theory of computation".

Comment: yes but there are multiple/infinite TMs/associated encodings that accept the same language & it is undecidable to check for equivalence....

Comment: @vzn So? Vor has shown that a Turing machine exists with the required property. His proof is non-constructive but why is that a problem?

Comment: is there some way to sketch out how it avoids the TM equivalence/multiple encodings issue? seems there is some room for slightly different interpretation of the question... would say its a subtlety that deserves some attn...

Comment: @vzn It avoids the equivalence issue by being non-constructive. All it says is that $M'$ exists; it doesn't tell you how to find it. Multiple codings aren't an issue: if the machine with coding 283 accepts only 283, it meets the specification, even if that machine can also be coded 1384 and 78136. If you're not happy with that, choose a one-to-one coding.

Comment: @vzn OK, so the title of the question does begin "Can I construct", though the question itself is just "Is there a Turing machine".

Comment: @vzn: I think that the OP should try to write a program (in some programming language other than TM) that prints itself, then modify it to parse an input and accept if and only if it matches itself (a (very) good programming exercise :-) :-)

Comment: @Vor I'm eager to understand this argument. Have you fixed the encoding function? what happens with your programming example if we give the program an encoding in any different programming language? I know this is a restatement of vzn's question. Sorry if it's annoying.

Comment: @MahmoudA.: it's not annoying, but I don't understand what you mean with "what happens with your programming example if we give the program an encoding in any different programming language". I didn't fixed the encoding function, I simply applied the Kleene's recursion theorem; but if you know any programming language it is easy to build a simple program that prints itself; then you can modify it to store its description in a variable instead of printing it and comparing it to the input.

Comment: For example, in Java: public class R{public static void main(String[] a){byte c[]={34};String x=new String(c);String s="public class R{public static void main(String[] a){byte c[]={34};String x=new String(c);String s=;System.out.println(s.substring(0,97)+x+s+x+s.substring(97));}}";System.out.println(s.substring(0,97)+x+s+x+s.substring(97));}}

Comment: Thanks for the Sipser reference. In that chapter a TM SELF is described that can print itself. Once I read it's description I figured it would be trivial to let it compare what it printed to the input and accept if they match.

Comment: I'm confused by these "non constructive" assertions. The s-m-n theorem is perfectly constructive, and gives an effective way (albeit a bit convoluted) to solve these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For the trivial reason that we can choose the coding to have the property we want. (Note that there is no unique way of coding.) For example, let $\langle - \rangle$ be any coding function for Turing machines and let $M_0$ be some Turing machine with $L(M_0) = \{0\}$.  Now, let
$$\langle M\rangle' = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } M=M_0 \\
\langle M \rangle+1 &\text{ if } \langle M\rangle < \langle M_0\rangle \\
\langle M \rangle &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

We have $L(M_0) = \{\langle M_0\rangle'\}$, as required.