# Can a Turing Machine tell if an input string is a description of itself?

Tags: turing-machines

Can some Turing Machine $M$ with description $\langle M\rangle$, check if an input string $w$ is a description of itself? That is, can $M$ be constructed such that $M$ can tell if $w$ = $\langle M\rangle$?

The closest related problem I could find was: [Can I construct a Turing machine that accepts only its own encoding?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18989/can-i-construct-a-turing-machine-that-accepts-only-its-own-encoding)

But I want to consider the case where $M$ must recognize its own description as an intermediate step, and then accept or reject based on that and some additional criteria. Is this possible?

Comment: The construction in the linked question doesn’t care what exactly the machine does. Any TM can be transformed in such a way, that it has access to its own encoding, no matter what further operations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, and this is a standard application of the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem) - the slogan for this theorem being, "you can assume at the *beginning* of your construction that you know what the index of the construction will be at the *end*."

Let me outline how it is applied in this case:

You have a description of the machine you want, *with* a "gap" - a point where you want to insert the code for the machine itself. This really defines a *family of* machines, where we have $M_k$ being the version where we stick in the number "$k$."

The process of building $M_k$, given $k$, is recursive; that is, the function sending $k$ to the index for $M_k$ is recursive.

Now on the face of it, that doesn't help since we just get an infinite regress: $M_0$ has index $5$, $M_5$ has index $17$, $M_{17}$ has index $2$, ... However, the recursion theorem lets us catch our tail. Let $f$ be the recursive function mentioned above, which sends $k$ to the index for $M_k$. Then by the recursion theorem, we get a fixed point for $f$: some $c$ such that the machine with index $c$ behaves identically to the machine with index $f(c)$.

But this means exactly that the machine $M_c$ - whose index is $f(c)$ - behaves as if it was given its *own* index! (Intuitively, it "thinks" it has index $c$, and that's good enough: index $c$ and index $f(c)$ are "the same.")